# When to use %s instead of %c?

Tags: c

Why it has `%s` instead of `%c`?

```c
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <conio.h>
    
void main()
{    
    clrscr();
    char fname[20], mname[20], lname[20];
    
    printf("Enter The First Name Middle Name & Last Name");
    scanf("%s %s %s",&fname, &mname, &lname);
    printf("Abbreviated name=%c. %c. %s", fname[0], mname[0], lname);
    
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Might I ask why you are using turbo C++? It is **VERY** old, and has not been updated since 2006. IMHO it should not be used anymore. Also, why are you using a C++ compiler for C code?

Comment: Oh, and `void main()` is non standard and should not be used. It's illegal in C++. use `int main()` and `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`

Comment: `%c` is for characters.  `%s` is for strings.  Characters and strings are *very* different.  A character is not just a "short string".  A character is not the same as a string of length 1.  A string is an *array* of characters.  You can't intermix the two.

Answer (score 1):

If the `%s` format specifier is used with the `scanf()` function, it is intended to read data from *stdin* to a `char` pointer. If the `%s` format specifier is used with the `printf()` function, it writes to *stdout* the characters that a `char` pointer represents in memory (up to the `'\0'` character).

There is an error in the use of the `scanf()` method because the name of the arrays is also the address of the array. In the example below, the format specifier `%s` is used in the `scanf()` method when reading data from `stdin`, since `fname`, `mname`, and `lname` are `char` pointers. Since `fname[0]` and `mname[0]` are `char` data, the format specifier `%c` was used when printing to *stdin*. Because `lname` is a `char` pointer, the format specifier `%s` was used when printing to *stdout*.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char fname[20], mname[20], lname[20];

    printf("Enter The First Name Middle Name & Last Name");
    // The error in the line below has been fixed.
    scanf("%s %s %s",fname, mname, lname);

    printf("Abbreviated name=%c. %c. %s", fname[0], mname[0], lname);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sercan, have you worked at Siemens in Berlin? ;-)